# Convert multiple boolean columns which names start with string `abc_` at once into integer dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to have 1 and 0 instead of True and False in a pandas data frame for only columns starting with abc_. Is there any better way of doing this other than my loop:

```
for col in df:
  if col[:4] =='abc_':
     df[col] = df[col].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `filter` and an in-place `update`.

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='^abc_').astype(int))
```

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:** converting **all** boolean (`dtype == 'bool'`) columns

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq('bool')] = df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq('bool')].astype(np.int8)
```

**Option 2:** if only those boolean columns that start with `abc_` should be converted:

```
col_mask = df.dtypes.eq('bool') & df.columns.str.contains('^abc_')
df.loc[:, col_mask] = df.loc[:, col_mask].astype(np.int8)
```

**Option 3:** converting only by column names

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.match(r'^abc_.*$')] = \
    df.filter(regex=r'^abc_').astype(np.int8)
```

Answer (score 5):

By using `str.contains`

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('abc_')]=df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('abc_')].astype(int)
```